# Azure app registration not allowing IDN

Tags: azure, entra-id, oauth, idn

I'm trying out Azure AD, to allow users to authenticate with their Microsoft account on my website. Oauth2 works fine when the redirect URI is `http://localhost:8080/callback`, but it fails when I try to enter the "real" IDN URI (`https://södermalmsskolan.com/callback`) in the portal, saying that the URI is invalid. I have also tried entering the punycode version (`https://xn--sdermalmsskolan-8sb.com`) but without any success. Am I doing something wrong?

[Here's a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7QDl.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft indeed has issues supporting a 17 years old standard.

I opened a support ticket, this is the answer:

> Based on our investigation, i could notice that the Redirect URls with
> IDN domain and Punycode is not supported as of now
>
> We have determined that we have ran into a product limitation and have
> no work around at this time.
>
> I encourage you to provide feedback to the Azure Product Groups for
> the resources you are using in your environment. You can do this
> through the Azure Feedback Forum. This forum allows you to provide
> suggestions for new features, ideas for improvements on current
> features, as well as general feedback, and then receive a response
> from the product group. It’s great to vote for ideas that you’d like
> to see implemented or come up with your own!
>
> Further,i would request you to write a feedback forum using the
> following link
> https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/38663206-support-for-idn-domain-names

Comment: And of course the feedback link is no longer valid, so we can’t upvote this request

Comment: It is now here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/607c6eaf-c625-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789